# Combining xargs, sed and command substitution

Tags: shell, xargs, command-substitution

I would expect under bash for the following:

```
 ls *.py | xargs -I{} echo $(echo {} | sed 's/\.py/_2\.py/g')
```

to list all .py files contained in the directory but with _2 annexed after the file name and before the .py extension.

Yet this is not what happens. It simply lists the .py files in the directory without any change.

In short:

```
$ ls
A.py  B.py

$ ls *.py | xargs -I{} echo $(echo {} | sed 's/\.py/_2\.py/g')
A.py
B.py
```

while the output I expected would've been:

```
A_2.py
B_2.py
```

What happens here and how to get the expected output?

Comment: Why not `ls *.py | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed 's/\.py/_2\.py/g'`?

Comment: @Philippos well, for this even `ls *.py | sed 's/\.py/_2\.py/g'` works... the reason is that this is testing, I want to replace the echo after the `-I{}` with a command like `cp`, `mv`, ...

Comment: In that case, don't parse the output of `ls` and use `find ... -exec ...` instead.
See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/364705

Comment: @Amaterasu Depends on what you do in the exec :-) `find . -type f -name '*.py' -exec sh -c 'a={}; mv "$a" "${a%.py}_2.py"' \;`

Comment: @markgraf yeah, well that works and you can have a "preview" what files will be renamed. `find -name "*.py" -exec cp -n {} {}_2 \; -exec rename .py_2 _2.py {} \;` otoh is less baroque but it can't be tested ... and is it really safe?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the command in subshell i.e.

```
echo {} | sed 's/\.py/_2\.py/g'
```

executes before echo, so after this command the command will be:

```
xargs -I{} echo {}
```

which will simply echo all the file_names.

You can use find command:

```
find directory_name -name '*.py' \
-exec rename 's/.py/_2.py/' {} +
```

It will rename all the files in just one command.

To find files in current directory only not subdirectories, use `maxdepth 1` option i.e.:

```
find directory_name -maxdepth 1 -name '*.py' \
-exec rename 's/.py/_2.py/' {} +
```

Comment: Can you also copy with that command `rename` in one pass?

Comment: Note that the user is only accessing `.py` files in the current directory. This makes the use of `find` unnecessary.

Comment: @Amaterasu this command will be like `rename 's/.py/_2.py/' file1.py file2.py ....`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360925/whats-the-difference-between-and-at-the-end-of-a-find-command

Comment: @Amaterasu no, but you can have more than one `-exec` in a single find command.  e.g. `-exec cp ... \;` first, followed by `-exec rename ... +`.  By default, the second `-exec` (rename) will only be run for files where the first (cp) returned true.